# How to randomly select nonzero elements and replace them with 0?

Tags: python, list

There is a list (`A = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 0, 6, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0]`), there is an requirement that in the list, the maximum number of nonzero elements is 5.

How can I randomly select nonzero elements and replace them with 0 and keep that there are only 5 nonzero element in the list?

Comment: What happens if there are less than 5?

Comment: What have you tried? This seems to be a rather trivial programming task.

Comment: @DaniMesejo: " the maximum number of nonzero elements is 5." - if there are less than 5, the requirement is already fulfilled

Comment: Why do you want to *randomly* select nonzero elements and not just those that come after the 5th nonzero element?

Comment: @mkrieger1 Thanks for you reply. I am just curious about how to randomly several nonzero elements and remove them from the list.

Comment: Have you tried to use the `random` module?

Comment: Congrats @Dani Mesejo. Go to 100K :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One approach is to sample without replacement the indices of the non-zero elements if the there are more than 5, as below:

```
import random

A = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 0, 6, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0]
non_zero = [i for i, ai in enumerate(A) if ai]
len_non_zero = len(non_zero)
sample = random.sample(non_zero, k=(len_non_zero - 5 if  len_non_zero > 5 else len_non_zero))

res = [ai for i, ai in enumerate(A) if i not in sample]
print(res)
```

**Output**

```
[0, 1, 2, 3, 5, 0, 6, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
```

Answer (score 2):

You could generate a random order to 'walk' through A, then do so, copying the first 5 non-zero numbers to a new list:

```
import random

A = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 0, 6, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0]
lenA = len(A)
B = [0] * lenA

count = 5

for i in random.sample(range(0, lenA), lenA):
  if count and A[i] != 0:
    B(i) = A[i]
    count = count - 1

print(B)
```

Comment: I'll leave this here, but I've just realised that the question actually wants removal, not replacement with 0.